# Понять luajit,или что я делаю не так?

Tags: переменные, lua

Вот имеем код из  Lua Performance Tips:

```
 local sin = math.sin
function foo (x)
for i = 1, 1000000 do
x = x + sin(i)
end
return x
end
print(foo(10))
```

на что luajit сообщает:

```
stdin:3: attempt to call global 'sin' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:3: in function 'foo'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x01000012d0
```

еще:
пишем таблицу в локальную переменную:

```
local a = {"abc", 123, true}
```

потом пробую напечатать ее третий ключ:

```
print (a[3])
```

на что интепретатор снова сообщает мне:

```
stdin:1: attempt to index global 'a' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x01000012d0
```

Что я делаю не так? Подскажите, плиз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, вы используете "живой" интерфейс (через командную строку). Он компилирует каждую функцию в собственном окружении, следовательно, локальные переменные не сохраняются. Попробуйте вставить код в файл, а потом запустить.

Альтернатива - обернуть в функцию:

```
x = function()
    ваш код здесь
end
x()
```

**UPD**:

Ещё один вариант, самый простой:

```
do
    ваш код здесь
end
```

Comment: Жму руку! Из файла все работает как надо.

Answer (score 1):

Не проще ли просто убрать префикс `local` из второго примера и вместо `sin` в первом примере поставить `math.sin`? Каждая строка в интерпретаторе **LuaJIT** выполняется также как и в просто интерпретаторе **Lua** - подобно `do <строка> end`. Так что никаких `local`'ов в строках если вы хотите использовать это в следующих строках!